# pdfbox printing a page results in IllegalArgumentException miter limit < 1

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to print a PDF document using pdfbox v2.0.21 and I use the following code for that:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(f);
PrintService myPrintService = findPrintService("Name of my printer");
                
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PDFPageable pageable = new PDFPageable(document);
job.setPageable(pageable);
job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
job.print();
```

When using it with different example PDFs this code works fine, but I want to print a PDF that I first crop to only show a specific part of the page.

When I try to print the cropped PDF, I get the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: miter limit < 1
```

and also a warning about a missing font like this:

```
[AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.apache.fontbox.ttf.PostScriptTable - No PostScript name information is provided for the font
```

I did not find many information about the miter limit, maybe it could be connected to cropping in the PDF document or maybe it could have something to do with the missing font. Any tips on how I could resolve this topic would be very much appreciated!

The stack trace of the error looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: miter limit < 1
    at java.awt.BasicStroke.<init>(BasicStroke.java:201)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.getStroke(PageDrawer.java:769)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.strokePath(PageDrawer.java:812)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.graphics.StrokePath.process(StrokePath.java:37)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:933)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:515)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:489)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:272)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderPageToGraphics(PDFRenderer.java:431)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPrintable.print(PDFPrintable.java:246)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.printPage(RasterPrinterJob.java:2165)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1547)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1390)
    at my.function.shipping.view.Panel.printDocument(Panel.java:659)
    at my.function.shipping.view.Panel.actionPerformed(Panel.java:733)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I added the stack trace of the error to the question. Unfortunately I cannot include my PDF since it contains customer information

Comment: Thanks that is what I expected. I'll fix it (will add a check in `org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.SetLineMiterLimit`) and will come back to you.

Comment: new version here, please try: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.22-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thank you very much for the change... I included the new snapshot in my build path and tried it again - but the error still looks very similar... Only two lines have changed in the stack trace - I updated it in the question ( at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.getStroke(PageDrawer.java:769)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.strokePath(PageDrawer.java:812))

Comment: I'll try a different approach tonight (I ignored SetLineMiterLimit is not the only place where it can be set, it could also appear in an ExtGState dictionary) and will come back to you.

Comment: Please try again https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.22-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Hi, ok so the error message is gone now... The rest is probably very specific to my PDF... I crop and rotate the first page, and leave the second page as it is... With the new version, PDFBox now gives me warnings about the first page "Miter limit must be >= 1, value 0.0 is ignored" and does not print the first page... The second page is printed out fine now

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug and has been fixed in version 2.0.22. The ticket is [PDFBOX-5019](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5019).